# Make the lines in the plot border

Tags: r

How is it possible to make the lines in the following plot to be more thick?

Here the input data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(google_before = c(0.26981640312419, 0.302252978236613, 
                                 0.27519244423907, 0.278573602172958), amazon_before = c(0.165541492443112, 
                                                                                         0.162543532408399, 0.150484069110868, 0.212810080358854), ebay_before = c(0.698096408083222, 
                                                                                                                                                                   0.625412783031095, 0.699099484936941, 0.610794910230257), yahoo_before = c(0.156164414439798, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.189265950612553, 0.151656203861282, 0.211930979296043), so_before = c(0.384820854982136, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.364443743167243, 0.352744936715994, 0.397252245652394), google_after = c(0.290892287578753, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.279948606399405, 0.262591995672118, 0.327138300630022), amazon_after = c(0.170072244074521, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.190821283262141, 0.136632592108377, 0.185400160041476), ebay_after = c(0.637122860008791, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.595805110056691, 0.713976579846045, 0.594306130039334), yahoo_after = c(0.154789410213351, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.185512865305938, 0.136271935262096, 0.18347290001916), so_after = c(0.359935532588727, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.391256325582968, 0.352913994612688, 0.312475345723399)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Here the approriate code transformation:

```
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "company_period", 
               values_to = "val") %>%
  separate(col = company_period, into = c("company", "period"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(company, period), as.factor)
```

And here the plot:

```
df_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, color = company, linetype = period)) +
  geom_density() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Also, I appreciate the sharing of reproducible data. Next time, you could simplify even more by sharing `dput(df_long)` directly, rather than sharing `df` and several lines of transformation code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `size` in `geom_density`. Try `size = 1`. (I think the default is 0.5)

```
df_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, color = company, linetype = period)) +
  geom_density(size = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```